# Oracle select all rows using the contains keyword

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-text

I'm looking for a character that I can use in an Oracle contains to get ALL results.

If I search for the string "test" in a title column I use this statement:

```
select * 
from my_table 
where contains (title, 
    '<query><textquery grammar="CTXCAT">test</textquery></query>') > 0
```

With this statement I get the rows which have the "test"-string included in title-column.

BUT: Is there any way to use contains and select ALL rows?

Comment: What type is that column? Is it CLOB?

Comment: Can you modify the where clause or must it follow the format contains(<info>) > 0?

Comment: DataColumn is type of VarChar.
No, that's the problem - I can not modify the where clause - have to use contains.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
select * from my_table
where title like 
    '<query><textquery grammar="CTXCAT">%</textquery></query>'
```

This uses the LIKE syntax and the % wildcard to achieve what I think you want.

Comment: No, I need to use the contains keyword :(

Comment: Why can you only use the CONTAINS keyword? LIKE is the way to do it

Comment: By using contains oracle is searching for each single word in any order.
Btw: I tried "like" - just for testing - and it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says wildcards with the Oracle Text `CONTAINS()` predicate are `%` and `_` just like the `LIKE` predicate.

Does the following work?  I don't have an instance of Oracle handy to test.

```
select * 
from my_table 
where contains (title, 
    '<query><textquery grammar="CTXCAT">%</textquery></query>') > 0
```

Comment: I checked the Oracle docs and % does work as a wildcard 
in text_query param of CONTAINS().  This is the right answer.

Comment: I tried this statement with "%" before and got an empty result table.